# Open dialog box using article_id buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dialog

Currently I'm setting up an adminpanel with some quick actions for my articles (in this case, deleting the article). Once I hit the trash can, a dialog should open and ask me to confess the deletion. It should open the same dialog, based on article_id. I dont really understand JavaScript that well (apart from the noobie stuff).

**Part of the PHP foreach code:**

```
foreach ($show_articles as $blog):
    echo "<div class='blog_articles_bottom_container'>";
        echo "<div class='blog_articles_bottom_title'>".$blog['title']."</div>";
        echo "<div class='blog_articles_bottom_date'>".date('j-m-Y, H:m', $blog['created_at'])."u</div>";
        echo "<div class='blog_articles_bottom_comments'>".$amount_comments['total']."</div>";
        echo "<div class='blog_articles_bottom_likes'>".$amount_likes['total']."</div>";
        echo "<div class='blog_articles_bottom_actions'>";
            echo "<div id='article_edit' class='blog_articles_bottom_actions_edit'></div>";
            echo "<div id='btn-article-remove-dialog-".$blog['article_id']."' class='blog_articles_bottom_actions_remove'></div>";
            echo "<div id='article_settings' class='blog_articles_bottom_actions_settings'></div>";
            echo "<div id='clear'></div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div id='clear'></div>";
    echo "</div>";
endforeach;
```

As you can see, the remove button has the following id: #id='btn-article-remove-dialog-".$blog['article_id']." which succesfully outputs: id='btn-article-remove-dialog-1" for the first article.

**This is the Dialog part:**

```
<div id="blog_articles_dialog-" class="blog_articles_dialog" title="Confess deletion">
Are you sure you want to delete </b>'".$blog['title']."'</b> ?
</div>
```

**This is the JavaScript part:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#blog_articles_dialog-"+article_id).dialog({ autoOpen: false, resizable: false, draggable: false, closeOnEscape: true, dialogClass: "alert-dialog", width: "380", modal: true });
    $( "#blog_articles_dialog-"+article_id).dialog({ hide: { effect: "clip", direction: "vertical", duration: 350 } });

    $( "#btn-article-remove-dialog-"+article_id).click(function(article_id) {
        $( "#blog_articles_dialog-"+article_id).dialog( "open" );
        console.log(article_id);
    });
});
```

My question is as following; How do I archive this? It curretly echo's 'Uncaught ReferenceError: article_id is not defined' in my console log. Tried to fix this but as I said, Im a nooblet.

Thanks

**EDIT #1 (@ViktorCarlén)**
It did not, so I added the following to it:

```
var article_id = $("#blog_articles_dialog-"+article_id);
```

The 'article_id is not defined' erro disappeared, but I've got 'Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #blog_articles_dialog-[object Object]' in return :(

Comment: In the javascript you supplied the variable 'article_id' is not defined anywhere. Does it exist outside of this scope?

Comment: @ViktorCarlén It did not, so I added this to it (not sure if its correct, but the old error disappeared and a new error appeared)

var article_id = $("#blog_articles_dialog-"+article_id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets cut out the last line in the dialog's id:

```
<div id="blog_articles_dialog" class="blog_articles_dialog" title="Confess deletion">
    Are you sure you want to delete </b>'".$blog['title']."'</b> ?
</div>
```

Then skip the article_id variable which doesn't exist.
(An empty function call like this serves the same as $(document).ready();)

```
$(function () {
    $("#blog_articles_dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, resizable: false, draggable: false, closeOnEscape: true, dialogClass: "alert-dialog", width: "380", modal: true });
    $("#blog_articles_dialog").dialog({ hide: { effect: "clip", direction: "vertical", duration: 350 }});
});
```

And then add : data-article-id="'.$blog['article_id'].'" to the element that triggers the remove dialog, the following should work:

```
$(".blog_articles_bottom_actions_remove").on('click', function (event) {
     $("#blog_articles_dialog").dialog("open");
     var article_id = $(this).attr('data-article-id');
     console.log(article_id);
});
```

Tell me if you want me to elaborate if it's unclear or not working properly.

Comment: Ofcourse, why didnt I think of using the data-attribute :| Thank you so much, it's working fine now! One quick question though, would it be smart to put the dialog inside the foreach?

Comment: Well, then you would create an identical dialog for each loop and that isn't very effective. But I doubt it has any big effect on performance overall, which would be the downside.

Comment: You're right about that.. Anyway, thank you once again!